# How to compile with all .jars in .m2?

Tags: command-line, maven, find, printf, javac

I'm trying debug `mvn compile` of a file with many dependencies with `javac`.

This is how I'm trying to do this:

```
CLASSPATH=`find ~/.m2 -name *.jar -print0`; javac -verbose BogusFile.java
```

My problem is that I'm not sure how to tell find to separate each jar found with the unix file separator (`:`).

Maybe the `-printf` has the solution?

Comment: is the BogusFile.java part of a maven project you try to debug? What are you trying to debug?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry I can not answer your question but give a possible other solution approach.

If you need to build a classpath for your maven project you can run the copy-dependencies goal of the [Maven Dependency Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) on your project:

```
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies
```

Maven will copy all dependencies for your project (also transitive) to the `target/dependency` directory and classpath can be set to `target/dependency/*;` (you still have to include your artifact jar).

**Example:**

Code:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.WordUtils;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Bogus {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Bogus.class);

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        LOG.debug(WordUtils.capitalize("hello world"));
    }
}
```

Directory:

```
C:.
│
├───src
│   └───main
│       └───java
│               Bogus.java
│
└───target
    └───dependency
            commons-lang-2.6.jar
            log4j-1.2.16.jar
```

Compile Command:

```
.....\bogus>javac -cp target\dependency\*; src\main\java\Bogus.java
```

Result:

```
C:.
│
├───src
│   └───main
│       └───java
│               Bogus.class
│               Bogus.java
│
└───target
    └───dependency
            commons-lang-2.6.jar
            log4j-1.2.16.jar
```

Comment: @K: the issue remains, i.e. how to separate each jar found with the unix file separator (:)?

Comment: @simpatico If you have all jars in one directory you can use wildcards to specify the classpath `target/dependency/*` (described [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)) - you do not need to mention every jar and thus do not need to separate them

Comment: @K: my understanding is that each jar is treated as classpath dir. So with multiple jars. But prove it with code!

Comment: @simpatico Please read the documentation (see link) regarding wildcards provided in the privious comment.

Comment: @K: had missed that part! But when I compile it it doesn't show that it picks up any of the jars in the CLASSPATH. Trying javac -verbose -cp target/dependency/* BogusFile.java
reports: javac: invalid flag: target/dependency/annotations-1.3.2.jar

Comment: @simpatico Use an absolute path to the target/dependency directory and try if that works.

Comment: @K: Will you please post a working example? $ javac -cp /Users/simpatico/ws/../target/dependency/* BogusFile.java 
javac: invalid flag: /Users/simpatico/ws/../target/dependency/activation-1.1.jar
Usage: javac <options> <source files>

Comment: @simpatico Added working example! You maybe failed because of the missing ';' (':') after the classpath. Just noticed myself that it has to be included.

Answer (score 3):

Join all the jars by `:` separator, to use as the classpath for the compiler.

```
export TEST_CLASSPATH=$(find ~/.m2 -name *.jar | sed -z 's/\n/:/g')
javac -classpath $TEST_CLASSPATH:./ BogusFile.java
```

Comment: @simpatico proposed an edit to replace Python with `sed`, which as such is probably a good idea, but their proposal had a bug, and anyway, it should probably be posted as a separate answer instead. Try `export TEST_CLASSPATH=$(find ~/.m2 -name *.jar -print | sed 's/\n/:/g')`